# collapsingToolbarLayout set title only when collapsed

Tags: android, listener, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to set `collapsingToolbarLayout` title only when it is collapsed

For that I set :

```
app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
```

And it's working good.

But on 4.2.2 app crash with following Log

```
STACK_TRACE

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:687)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:666)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:633)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.ensureExpandedTexture(CollapsingTextHelper.java:405)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setInterpolatedTextSize(CollapsingTextHelper.java:382)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.calculateOffsets(CollapsingTextHelper.java:227)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setExpansionFraction(CollapsingTextHelper.java:203)
    at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout$OffsetUpdateListener.onOffsetChanged(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:754)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.dispatchOffsetUpdates(AppBarLayout.java:851)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.setAppBarTopBottomOffset(AppBarLayout.java:834)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.scroll(AppBarLayout.java:793)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onNestedScroll(AppBarLayout.java:644)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onNestedScroll(AppBarLayout.java:583)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout.java:1428)
    at android.support.v4.view.eh.a(ViewParentCompat.java:97)
    at android.support.v4.view.ec.a(ViewParentCompat.java:330)
    at android.support.v4.view.bk.a(NestedScrollingChildHelper.java:162)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchNestedScroll(RecyclerView.java:8306)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1387)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2209)
```

Please suggest me the correct way to implement it.

OR

Is there any `Listener` to detect whether `collapsingToolbarLayout`  collapsed so I can Hide/Unhide `ToolBar` title...

OR

Is it possible to set `collapsingToolbarLayout` title aligned with the another view I want...

Comment: did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170596/collapsingtoolbarlayout-crash?

Comment: @PareshMayani yes sir, But expanded Title Text Appearance starts from transparent to Black while collapsing..

Answer (score 16):

Final `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is as follows:-

```
collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Create Delivery Personnel");
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transperent));
collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: For transparent color make use of this:          collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Comment: This won't work as already noted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662416/show-collapsingtoolbarlayout-title-only-when-collapsed

Answer (score 8):

You can add listener to AppBar with this you can listen wether collapsed or not.

```
final Toolbar tool = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
CollapsingToolbarLayout c = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
AppBarLayout appbar = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
tool.setTitle("");
setSupportActionBar(tool);
c.setTitleEnabled(false);

appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {

    boolean isVisible = true;
    int scrollRange = -1;
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (scrollRange == -1) {
            scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        }
        if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
           tool.setTitle("Title");
            isVisible = true;
        } else if(isVisible) {
            tool.setTitle("");
            isVisible = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

i found the same problem today. I finally solved it by defining it on xml

```
app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
```

And also, checking for pre-kitkat programmatically

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    mCollapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.TransparentText)
};
```

Where TransparentText style is

```
<style name="TransparentText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
       <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

I know this is super late, but i hope this can help the others :)

Comment: what about kitkat and above version?

Comment: ok working fine... but i want one more thing and i think in which you would help me. I want the title marquee and it is working in jellybean but not above that. here is the code i used-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097126/marquee-title-in-toolbar-actionbar-in-android-with-lollipop-sdk?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: It doesnt work in Android 6.0 and above. The above answer works.

Comment: This also won't work as already noted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662416/show-collapsingtoolbarlayout-title-only-when-collapsed

Answer (score 0):

There is one workaround that I found:

On the `CollapsingToolbar`, set this:

```
app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/PosterText"
```

and in your styles add:

```
<style name="PosterText" parent="TextAppearance.Booksy.Headline5">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

This will give you a much less janky experience as the expanded title is still at the top.

Another way you could achieve this is instead of setting `expandedTitleGravity`, you could set `app:titleCollapseMode="fade"`, but this currently has an issue where it does not respect the expanded titles transparency  and just turns it to the opaque color (black in the above case).

I will let you know if I manage to solve it.